# Consultar dato en HashTable C#

Tags: c#, hashmap, hash, c#-8.0

Como estan?. Tengo un problema. Soy novato implementando tablas hash en C#. Estoy realizando un programa que entre las muchas características, una de ellas es consultar sin embargo tengo problemas. Lo que quiero hacer es que si la key es igual al dato ingresado es igual entonces me va a guardar en una variable tipo Persona el objeto que encontro con dicha key.
Pero no se cual es el metodo a utilizar para realizar esto... Se que en Java es .get(key), pero en c# no. Gracias.

Ya lo encontre en la documentacion pero no me aparece en las opciones de .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        private void consultarPersona(HashMap<string, Persona> tablaRegistro)
        {
            if(tablaRegistro.ContainsKey(txtPasaporteC.Text) == true)
            {
                Persona persona = tablaRegistro.

            }

        }
```

Comment: Estas desarrollando un proyecto mobile? porque en la imagen veo que muestras una libreria que es de Android en Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

El equivalente del `HashMap<>` en `C#` es `Dictionary<>`

Entonces puedes definir

```
Dictionary<string, Persona> tablaRegistro= new Dictionary<string, Persona>();
//aqui agregas datos
tablaRegistro.Add("key", new Persona(){ ... });
```

Y luego aplicarlo usando

```
    private void consultarPersona(Dictionary<string, Persona> tablaRegistro)
    {
        if(tablaRegistro.ContainsKey(txtPasaporteC.Text))
        {
            //si la key existe puede acceder a esta y asignar un valor
            tablaRegistro[key] = new Persona(){ ... };
        }

    }
```

[C# Java HashMap equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent)

Comment: Muchas gracias.